# How to make a panel scroll?

Tags: extjs3

```
 var gridForm3 = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'Main-form2',
        frame: true,
        labelAlign: 'left',
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'fit',   
        items: [

        gridtree

        ]

        ,renderTo:Ext.getBody()
    });
```

This is my code. I am not getting scroll bar to the panel. What I should do?

Comment: Is your grid displayed correctly? Or have you just nothing displayed?

Comment: grid is displaying properly.

Comment: Grid is displaying. Because there is no scroll bar,I could see only few columns

Comment: I don't really use the third version of extjs but in extjs 4.2 you only have to put the parent container of your grid with a 'fit' layout (no need of the autoScroll).